# Stop creating new instance of any third app while launching it in android

Tags: android, package-managers

In my app I am launching any third party app (e.g. messaging app) by using this code

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.mms");
intent.setFlags(805306368);
startActivity(intent);
```

I can successfully launch and can resume the app if it is already running in background.
 But when I launch the same messaging app from my outside the app it creates new instance of messaging app on the above of my already launched messaging app from my app .I don't want to create new instance of messaging app if it is launched manually from my phone.I have tried some flags like `single top , clear top` etc. But it always created new instance.. 
Does anyone have any solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I launch the same messaging app from my outside the app it creates new instance of messaging app on the above of my already launched messaging app from my app .

That is up to the authors of the other apps, not you. You may have some control over which task the activity that *you* start goes into. You do not have any control over tasks for anything else, such as an app that you did not write (the home screen) uses when starting another app that you did not write (the messaging app).